# Playwright - How to access test results before running globalTeardown

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

In Playwright, after all tests have been executed, I am running a **globalTeardown** file that would send all of the test results to an external test management tool by making a series of api calls.

My intention was to access the jUnit.xml file and get the temporary test results from there, but the problem is that that file doesn't generate until the entire run is over, which is after the **globalTeardown** call.

Is there a way with Playwright to access the temporary test results, before the run is over?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Bmoe You'll have to write a custom method that accesses testInfo at the end of each test run in test.AfterAll() and then send the data to a file. After that, you can access the data in that file before the globalTeardown call and do whatever you need to do with it.